# Action that parents to do their kids by sponsoring their lives

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the verb for an action that would describe an action / process of maintaining / sponsoring life of the children by their parents. Meaning that kids do not need to bother about earning money in order to survive.

> Up until 18 years old, kids are being ______ by their parents.

Comment: *Supported*, perhaps?

Comment: guess 'raised' is too hackneyed and old school.

Comment: _Bankrolled_ is sometimes used, but is possibly a little harsh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean supplied with the money to live, Mick’s suggestion of *supported* is corrected.

If you mean more of an emotional connection, there is *nurtured* and *cared for*.

*Housed* means literally kept in a house.